# reCaptcha Aldeed:Autoform (Meteor) - Not working?

Tags: meteor, recaptcha

I have a similar problem to this guy:
[How do I integrate Google's reCaptcha inside aldeed:autoform (meteor)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31993517/how-do-i-integrate-googles-recaptcha-inside-aldeedautoform-meteor)

I tried the solution offered there but it didn't work. 
On my contact.js :

```
    AutoForm.hooks({
    App_kontakt: {
        onSubmit: function (formData, recaptchaResponse) {
             var formData = {
            //get the data from your form fields
        };

        //get the captcha data
        var recaptchaResponse = grecaptcha.getResponse();

        Meteor.call('formSubmissionMethod', formData, recaptchaResponse, function(error, result) {
            if (result && result.success === false) {
      //CAPTCHA failed
      Modal.show('recaptcha');
    }
return false;

        });
```

On my main.js (Server side)

```
 Meteor.methods({
formSubmissionMethod: function(formData, captchaData) {

        var verifyCaptchaResponse = reCAPTCHA.verifyCaptcha(this.connection.clientAddress, captchaData);

        if (!verifyCaptchaResponse.success) {
            console.log('reCAPTCHA check failed!', verifyCaptchaResponse);
            throw new Meteor.Error(422, 'reCAPTCHA Failed: ' + verifyCaptchaResponse.error);
        } else
            console.log('reCAPTCHA verification passed!');

        //do stuff with your formData

        return true;
    },
  sendEmail: function(doc) {

    // Build the e-mail text
    var text = "Name: " + doc.name + "\n\n"
            + "E-Mail: " + doc.email + "\n\n\n\n"
            + "Telefonnummer: " + doc.phone + "\n\n"
            + doc.message;

    this.unblock();

    // Send the e-mail
    //Email.send({
      //  to: "....",
       // from: doc.email,
      //  subject: "Neue Nachricht von: " + doc.name,
     //   text: text
  //  });
  //
  console.log('SENT!!!');
  }
});
```

I just can't figure out a solution.. I can solve the reCaptcha but it does not matter if I do or not. The form will send anyways... 
Since the other thread was from 2015 I will just create an other one.

Comment: Your approach overall seems legitimate. I would focus on the `reCAPTCHA.verifyCaptcha(this.connection.clientAddress, captchaData); ` part and find out if is really a problem of reCAPTCHA or your code.

Comment: The thing is if I follow this documentation: https://libraries.io/meteor/ayue:recaptcha I will get it so far that it says in my console if I either pass the recaptcha or not. But still. Even if I dont pass it it will send. If I use hooks it just sends it.